# ¿Cómo obtener de 2 filas no consecutivas dada condición previa establecida, la diferencia en minutos de la fecha en SQL SERVER?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Hola buen día para todos!

Pido si podrán dar una mano con el siguiente problema que se me presentó.

Quiero obtener la diferencia en minutos entre 2 filas no consecutivas. Mis condiciones para hacer la diferencia son que sea el mismo "NODO" y el mismo "SURTIDOR".

El problema es tanto los nodos como los surtidores no son siempre consecutivos, entonces no siempre obtengo la diferencia que estoy buscando.
Dado esta limitante, entiendo que el camino no va por la función LAG, por eso les pido ayuda.

```
select nodo,surtidor, fecha_hora_despacho,
case when ((nodo = (LAG (nodo) over (order by fecha_hora_despacho))) 
         and surtidor = (LAG (surtidor) over (order by fecha_hora_despacho)))
    then ABS(DATEDIFF(Minute, fecha_hora_despacho, LAG (fecha_hora_despacho) over (order by fecha_hora_despacho))) 
    else 0 end as Diferencia_Despacho
from DESPACHOS
```

Como dato adicional, el 0 del ELSE es a modo descarte y ya he ordenado por los campos también pero sigo sin obtener lo que busco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias y saludos!!!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y porque ordenas solamente por fecha? no deberias ordenar por nodo y surtidor tambien?

Comment: Hola! como estas? Muchas gracias por el consejo, corregí y readecué la publicación. 
Probé de ordenar por nodo y surtidor también, pero sigo con el mismo problema.

Comment: Podrias mostrar como probaste ordenar por nodo y surtidor?

Comment: Hola! Si, probé de varias formas, alterando el orden y no incluyendo en una de las condiciones y en la otra si, pero sigue el problema.

select nodo,surtidor, fecha_hora_despacho,
case when ((nodo = (LAG (nodo) over (order by nodo, surtidor, fecha_hora_despacho))) 
   and surtidor = (LAG (surtidor) over (order by nodo, surtidor,fecha_hora_despacho)))
 then ABS(DATEDIFF(Minute, fecha_hora_despacho, LAG (fecha_hora_despacho) over (order by fecha_hora_despacho))) 
 else 0 end as Diferencia_Despacho
from DESPACHOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear [*particiones* en las funciones de ventana](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#partition-by), que sirven justamente para lograr lo que quieres.

Cuando haces una partición, los datos son primero *segmentados* de acuerdo a la partición, luego ordenados y finalmente sobre esos conjuntos de datos separados se aplica la función de ventana.

La partición se crea dentro de la cláusula `over` con la cláusula `partition by`, seguida de una lista de los campos que componen la partición (similar a la cláusula `group by`).

Un ejemplo sencillo que te muestra en cada fila la fecha de despacho anterior del mismo nodo y surtidor, a la par de la fecha de despacho anterior general, sería:

```
select   nodo
       , surtidor
       , fecha_hora_despacho
       , lag(fecha_hora_despacho) over (partition by nodo, surtidor order by fecha_hora_despacho) fecha_hora_despacho_anterior_mismo_nodo_surtidor
       , lag(fecha_hora_despacho) over (order by fecha_hora_despacho) fecha_hora_despacho_anterior_general
  from DESPACHOS
 order by fecha_hora_despacho;
```

Sobre esta consulta, sacar la diferencia de tiempo entre ambos camos debiera resultarte trivial.

Comment: Hola jachguate! Muchisimas Gracias!!! Apliqué el partition by y funcionó!!! Tema resuelto, agradezco tu pronta respuesta!